# Select into #TempTable from @Variable results to Cartesian Product

Tags: sql, sql-server, global-variables, global-temp-tables

Insert a table variable into a TempTable with multiple columns (ID, Number, etc.)

One of the table variables is:

```
DECLARE @@gvTempTable TABLE (Number bigint, ID int) 

insert into  @@gvTempTable (Number) values ('21212321332332');
insert into  @@gvTempTable (Number) values ('100000000000');
insert into  @@gvTempTable (ID) values ('1');
insert into  @@gvTempTable (ID) values ('12');

select * into ##GlobalTempTable from @@gvTempTable;
select * from ##GlobalTempTable;
```

I need to display ID and Number as one row without NULL

This returns a kind of Cartesian Product:

```
[![Current vs Desired result set][1]][1]
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/twal9.png]

Comment: `values ('21212321332332', 1), ('100000000000', 12)`

Comment: you need to describe more in details, what is the logic here

Comment: This worked for small number of records. But did not for large one. I got this message: Msg 10738, Level 15, State 1, Line 1006
The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values.

Comment: To bypass it I need to repeat the Insert Into @@gvTempTable(...) every thousand rows.

Answer (score 0):

this will gives you the desired result

```
select  Number = min(Number), ID = min(ID)
into    ##GlobalTempTable
from
(
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by case when Number IS NULL then 1 else 2 end order by ID) 
    from    @@gvTempTable
) d
group by rn
```